# Eventos no three.js e CSS não funcionam em alguns devices em alguns tamanhos

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries, three.js

A ideia é fazer um predio 3d e quando clicar em um apartamento abrir do lado (cada um ocupando metade da tela) um card com algumas informações, em devices com largura de até 650px, o card deve abrir sobrepondo a maquete (ambos passam a ocupar toda a tela em vez da metade)

No desktop funciona como esperado, porém ao mudar para o tipo Desktop (touch) nas ferramentas de desenvolvedor, o evento de click não é chamado
(coloquei um `console.log('teste')` e não mostra nada)

Ao diminuir a tela para 650px (valor do media query no css), tanto o desktop touch como o no touch, não funciona o evento (não mostra nada no console)

Ao usar o tipo mobile no touch os eventos do three funcionam normalmente em qualquer tamanho porém o css não funciona (mesmo em telas menores que 650px a tela continua dividida em dois)

Com o mobile touch, nem os eventos do three (não mostra nada no console) nem o css funciona a tela continua dividida em dois)

Estou usando a biblioteca [THREEx](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex.domevents) para poder usar eventos nos objetos

```js
// - - - - - Biblioteca THREEx - - - - - 

var THREEx  = THREEx   || {};

// # Constructor
THREEx.DomEvents = function(camera, domElement)
{
 this._camera = camera || null;
 this._domElement= domElement || document;
 this._raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
 this._selected = null;
 this._boundObjs = {};
 // Bind dom event for mouse and touch
 var _this = this;

 this._$onClick  = function(){ _this._onClick.apply(_this, arguments);  };
 this._$onDblClick = function(){ _this._onDblClick.apply(_this, arguments); };
 this._$onMouseMove = function(){ _this._onMouseMove.apply(_this, arguments); };
 this._$onMouseDown = function(){ _this._onMouseDown.apply(_this, arguments); };
 this._$onMouseUp = function(){ _this._onMouseUp.apply(_this, arguments);  };
 this._$onTouchMove = function(){ _this._onTouchMove.apply(_this, arguments); };
 this._$onTouchStart = function(){ _this._onTouchStart.apply(_this, arguments); };
 this._$onTouchEnd = function(){ _this._onTouchEnd.apply(_this, arguments); };
 this._$onContextmenu = function(){ _this._onContextmenu.apply(_this, arguments); };
 this._domElement.addEventListener( 'click' , this._$onClick , false );
 this._domElement.addEventListener( 'dblclick' , this._$onDblClick , false );
 this._domElement.addEventListener( 'mousemove' , this._$onMouseMove , false );
 this._domElement.addEventListener( 'mousedown' , this._$onMouseDown , false );
 this._domElement.addEventListener( 'mouseup' , this._$onMouseUp , false );
 this._domElement.addEventListener( 'touchmove' , this._$onTouchMove , false );
 this._domElement.addEventListener( 'touchstart' , this._$onTouchStart , false );
 this._domElement.addEventListener( 'touchend' , this._$onTouchEnd , false );
 this._domElement.addEventListener( 'contextmenu', this._$onContextmenu , false );
 
}

// # Destructor
THREEx.DomEvents.prototype.destroy = function()
{
 // unBind dom event for mouse and touch
 this._domElement.removeEventListener( 'click'  , this._$onClick , false );
 this._domElement.removeEventListener( 'dblclick' , this._$onDblClick , false );
 this._domElement.removeEventListener( 'mousemove' , this._$onMouseMove , false );
 this._domElement.removeEventListener( 'mousedown' , this._$onMouseDown , false );
 this._domElement.removeEventListener( 'mouseup'  , this._$onMouseUp , false );
 this._domElement.removeEventListener( 'touchmove' , this._$onTouchMove , false );
 this._domElement.removeEventListener( 'touchstart' , this._$onTouchStart , false );
 this._domElement.removeEventListener( 'touchend' , this._$onTouchEnd , false );
 this._domElement.removeEventListener( 'contextmenu' , this._$onContextmenu , false );
}

THREEx.DomEvents.eventNames = [
 "click",
 "dblclick",
 "mouseover",
 "mouseout",
 "mousemove",
 "mousedown",
 "mouseup",
 "contextmenu",
 "touchstart",
 "touchend"
];

THREEx.DomEvents.prototype._getRelativeMouseXY = function(domEvent){
 var element = domEvent.target || domEvent.srcElement;
 if (element.nodeType === 3) {
  element = element.parentNode; // Safari fix -- see http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html
 }
 
 //get the real position of an element relative to the page starting point (0, 0)
 //credits go to brainjam on answering http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755312/getting-mouse-position-relative-to-content-area-of-an-element
 var elPosition = { x : 0 , y : 0};
 var tmpElement = element;
 //store padding
 var style = getComputedStyle(tmpElement, null);
 elPosition.y += parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("padding-top"), 10);
 elPosition.x += parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("padding-left"), 10);
 //add positions
 do {
  elPosition.x += tmpElement.offsetLeft;
  elPosition.y += tmpElement.offsetTop;
  style  = getComputedStyle(tmpElement, null);

  elPosition.x += parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("border-left-width"), 10);
  elPosition.y += parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("border-top-width"), 10);
 } while(tmpElement = tmpElement.offsetParent);
 
 var elDimension = {
  width : (element === window) ? window.innerWidth : element.offsetWidth,
  height : (element === window) ? window.innerHeight : element.offsetHeight
 };
 
 return {
  x : +((domEvent.pageX - elPosition.x) / elDimension.width ) * 2 - 1,
  y : -((domEvent.pageY - elPosition.y) / elDimension.height) * 2 + 1
 };
};


/********************************************************************************/
/*  domevent context      */
/********************************************************************************/

// handle domevent context in object3d instance

THREEx.DomEvents.prototype._objectCtxInit = function(object3d){
 object3d._3xDomEvent = {};
}
THREEx.DomEvents.prototype._objectCtxDeinit = function(object3d){
 delete object3d._3xDomEvent;
}
THREEx.DomEvents.prototype._objectCtxIsInit = function(object3d){
 return object3d._3xDomEvent ? true : false;
}
THREEx.DomEvents.prototype._objectCtxGet  = function(object3d){
 return object3d._3xDomEvent;
}

/********************************************************************************/
/*          */
/********************************************************************************/

/**
 * Getter/Setter for camera
*/
THREEx.DomEvents.prototype.camera = function(value)
{
 if( value ) this._camera = value;
 return this._camera;
}

THREEx.DomEvents.prototype.bind = function(object3d, eventName, callback, useCapture)
{
 console.assert( THREEx.DomEvents.eventNames.indexOf(eventName) !== -1, "not available events:"+eventName );

 if( !this._objectCtxIsInit(object3d) ) this._objectCtxInit(object3d);
 var objectCtx = this._objectCtxGet(object3d); 
 if( !objectCtx[eventName+'Handlers'] ) objectCtx[eventName+'Handlers'] = [];

 objectCtx[eventName+'Handlers'].push({
  callback : callback,
  useCapture : useCapture
 });
 
 // add this object in this._boundObjs
 if( this._boundObjs[eventName] === undefined ){
  this._boundObjs[eventName] = []; 
 }
 this._boundObjs[eventName].push(object3d);
}
THREEx.DomEvents.prototype.addEventListener = THREEx.DomEvents.prototype.bind

THREEx.DomEvents.prototype.unbind = function(object3d, eventName, callback, useCapture)
{
 console.assert( THREEx.DomEvents.eventNames.indexOf(eventName) !== -1, "not available events:"+eventName );

 if( !this._objectCtxIsInit(object3d) ) this._objectCtxInit(object3d);

 var objectCtx = this._objectCtxGet(object3d);
 if( !objectCtx[eventName+'Handlers'] ) objectCtx[eventName+'Handlers'] = [];

 var handlers = objectCtx[eventName+'Handlers'];
 for(var i = 0; i < handlers.length; i++){
  var handler = handlers[i];
  if( callback != handler.callback ) continue;
  if( useCapture != handler.useCapture ) continue;
  handlers.splice(i, 1)
  break;
 }
 // from this object from this._boundObjs
 var index = this._boundObjs[eventName].indexOf(object3d);
 console.assert( index !== -1 );
 this._boundObjs[eventName].splice(index, 1);
}
THREEx.DomEvents.prototype.removeEventListener = THREEx.DomEvents.prototype.unbind

THREEx.DomEvents.prototype._bound = function(eventName, object3d)
{
 var objectCtx = this._objectCtxGet(object3d);
 if( !objectCtx ) return false;
 return objectCtx[eventName+'Handlers'] ? true : false;
}

/********************************************************************************/
/*  onMove        */
/********************************************************************************/

// # handle mousemove kind of events

THREEx.DomEvents.prototype._onMove = function(eventName, mouseX, mouseY, origDomEvent)
{
//console.log('eventName', eventName, 'boundObjs', this._boundObjs[eventName])
 // get objects bound to this event
 var boundObjs = this._boundObjs[eventName];
 if( boundObjs === undefined || boundObjs.length === 0 ) return;
 // compute the intersection
 var vector = new THREE.Vector2();

 // update the picking ray with the camera and mouse position
 vector.set( mouseX, mouseY );
 this._raycaster.setFromCamera( vector, this._camera ); 

 var intersects = this._raycaster.intersectObjects( boundObjs );

 var oldSelected = this._selected;
 
 if( intersects.length > 0 ){
  var notifyOver, notifyOut, notifyMove;
  var intersect = intersects[ 0 ];
  var newSelected = intersect.object;
  this._selected = newSelected;
  // if newSelected bound mousemove, notify it
  notifyMove = this._bound('mousemove', newSelected);

  if( oldSelected != newSelected ){
   // if newSelected bound mouseenter, notify it
   notifyOver = this._bound('mouseover', newSelected);
   // if there is a oldSelect and oldSelected bound mouseleave, notify it
   notifyOut = oldSelected && this._bound('mouseout', oldSelected);
  }
 }else{
  // if there is a oldSelect and oldSelected bound mouseleave, notify it
  notifyOut = oldSelected && this._bound('mouseout', oldSelected);
  this._selected = null;
 }


 // notify mouseMove - done at the end with a copy of the list to allow callback to remove handlers
 notifyMove && this._notify('mousemove', newSelected, origDomEvent, intersect);
 // notify mouseEnter - done at the end with a copy of the list to allow callback to remove handlers
 notifyOver && this._notify('mouseover', newSelected, origDomEvent, intersect);
 // notify mouseLeave - done at the end with a copy of the list to allow callback to remove handlers
 notifyOut  && this._notify('mouseout' , oldSelected, origDomEvent, intersect);
}


/********************************************************************************/
/*  onEvent        */
/********************************************************************************/

// # handle click kind of events

THREEx.DomEvents.prototype._onEvent = function(eventName, mouseX, mouseY, origDomEvent)
{
 //console.log('eventName', eventName, 'boundObjs', this._boundObjs[eventName])
 // get objects bound to this event
 var boundObjs = this._boundObjs[eventName];
 if( boundObjs === undefined || boundObjs.length === 0 ) return;
 // compute the intersection
 var vector = new THREE.Vector2();

 // update the picking ray with the camera and mouse position
 vector.set( mouseX, mouseY );
 this._raycaster.setFromCamera( vector, this._camera ); 

 var intersects = this._raycaster.intersectObjects( boundObjs, true);
 // if there are no intersections, return now
 if( intersects.length === 0 ) return;

 // init some variables
 var intersect = intersects[0];
 var object3d = intersect.object;
 var objectCtx = this._objectCtxGet(object3d);
 var objectParent = object3d.parent;

 while ( typeof(objectCtx) == 'undefined' && objectParent )
 {
     objectCtx = this._objectCtxGet(objectParent);
     objectParent = objectParent.parent;
 }
 if( !objectCtx ) return;

 // notify handlers
 this._notify(eventName, object3d, origDomEvent, intersect);
}

THREEx.DomEvents.prototype._notify = function(eventName, object3d, origDomEvent, intersect)
{
 var objectCtx = this._objectCtxGet(object3d);
 var handlers = objectCtx ? objectCtx[eventName+'Handlers'] : null;
 
 // parameter check
 console.assert(arguments.length === 4)

 // do bubbling
 if( !objectCtx || !handlers || handlers.length === 0 ){
  object3d.parent && this._notify(eventName, object3d.parent, origDomEvent, intersect);
  return;
 }
 
 // notify all handlers
 var handlers = objectCtx[eventName+'Handlers'];
 for(var i = 0; i < handlers.length; i++){
  var handler = handlers[i];
  var toPropagate = true;
  handler.callback({
   type  : eventName,
   target  : object3d,
   origDomEvent : origDomEvent,
   intersect : intersect,
   stopPropagation : function(){
    toPropagate = false;
   }
  });
  if( !toPropagate ) continue;
  // do bubbling
  if( handler.useCapture === false ){
   object3d.parent && this._notify(eventName, object3d.parent, origDomEvent, intersect);
  }
 }
}

/********************************************************************************/
/*  handle mouse events      */
/********************************************************************************/
// # handle mouse events

THREEx.DomEvents.prototype._onMouseDown = function(event){ return this._onMouseEvent('mousedown', event); }
THREEx.DomEvents.prototype._onMouseUp = function(event){ return this._onMouseEvent('mouseup' , event); }


THREEx.DomEvents.prototype._onMouseEvent = function(eventName, domEvent)
{
 var mouseCoords = this._getRelativeMouseXY(domEvent);
 this._onEvent(eventName, mouseCoords.x, mouseCoords.y, domEvent);
}

THREEx.DomEvents.prototype._onMouseMove = function(domEvent)
{
 var mouseCoords = this._getRelativeMouseXY(domEvent);
 this._onMove('mousemove', mouseCoords.x, mouseCoords.y, domEvent);
 this._onMove('mouseover', mouseCoords.x, mouseCoords.y, domEvent);
 this._onMove('mouseout' , mouseCoords.x, mouseCoords.y, domEvent);
}

THREEx.DomEvents.prototype._onClick  = function(event)
{
 // TODO handle touch ?
 this._onMouseEvent('click' , event);
}
THREEx.DomEvents.prototype._onDblClick  = function(event)
{
 // TODO handle touch ?
 this._onMouseEvent('dblclick' , event);
}

THREEx.DomEvents.prototype._onContextmenu = function(event)
{
 //TODO don't have a clue about how this should work with touch..
 this._onMouseEvent('contextmenu' , event);
}

/********************************************************************************/
/*  handle touch events      */
/********************************************************************************/
// # handle touch events


THREEx.DomEvents.prototype._onTouchStart = function(event){ return this._onTouchEvent('touchstart', event); }
THREEx.DomEvents.prototype._onTouchEnd = function(event){ return this._onTouchEvent('touchend' , event); }

THREEx.DomEvents.prototype._onTouchMove = function(domEvent)
{
 if( domEvent.touches.length != 1 ) return undefined;

 domEvent.preventDefault();

 var mouseX = +(domEvent.touches[ 0 ].pageX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
 var mouseY = -(domEvent.touches[ 0 ].pageY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
 this._onMove('mousemove', mouseX, mouseY, domEvent);
 this._onMove('mouseover', mouseX, mouseY, domEvent);
 this._onMove('mouseout' , mouseX, mouseY, domEvent);
}

THREEx.DomEvents.prototype._onTouchEvent = function(eventName, domEvent)
{
 if( domEvent.touches.length != 1 ) return undefined;

 domEvent.preventDefault();

 var mouseX = +(domEvent.touches[ 0 ].pageX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
 var mouseY = -(domEvent.touches[ 0 ].pageY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
 this._onEvent(eventName, mouseX, mouseY, domEvent); 
}




// - - - - - Meu Código (parte dele) - - - - - 




// Elemento em que o Three irá renderizar
const container = document.querySelector('.webgl');

// Cena
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
scene.rotation.y = -0.25;

// Camera
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, container.clientWidth / container.clientWidth, 0.01, 1000);
camera.position.z = 30;
camera.position.y = 10;

// Renderizador
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientWidth);
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// Eventos
const domEvents = new THREEx.DomEvents(camera, renderer.domElement)

// Prédio
const boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(7, 13, 7);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x85b9dd});
let edifice = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, material);
edifice.position.x = 0;
edifice.position.y = 10;
edifice.position.z = 0;
scene.add(edifice);

domEvents.addEventListener(edifice, 'click', function() {
    console.log('test'); //Não mostra nada quando clica no bloco
}, false);

// Movimentação: No foco ou click das setas
const leftArrow = document.querySelector('i.left');
const rightArrow = document.querySelector('i.right');
let move = false;

leftArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
    move = -0.03;
    setTimeout(() => move = -0.05, 100);
    setTimeout(() => move = -0.07, 200);
    setTimeout(() => move = -0.1, 300);
    setTimeout(() => move = -0.005, 400);
});
leftArrow.addEventListener('mouseover', () => move = -0.005);
leftArrow.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => move = false);

rightArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
    move = 0.03;
    setTimeout(() => move = 0.05, 100);
    setTimeout(() => move = 0.07, 200);
    setTimeout(() => move = 0.1, 300);
    setTimeout(() => move = 0.005, 400);
});
rightArrow.addEventListener('mouseover', () => move = 0.005);
rightArrow.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => move = false);

// Inicialização da animação
(function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    if(move) {
        scene.rotation.y += move;
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
})();

document.querySelector('canvas').setAttribute('title', 'Clique em um apartamento para ver mais informações')

document.querySelector('.info-content button').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    document.querySelector('.info-content').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.info-title').style.marginTop = '45vh';
});
```

```css
body {
 font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
 margin: 0;
}

.model {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.webgl, .info {
 display: flex;
 flex: 1;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.info-title {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 3rem;
 margin-top: 30vh;
    transition: margin-top 1s ease-in-out;
}
.info-content {
 transition: display 1s ease-in-out;
 display: none;
 width: 70%;
 height: 50%;
 margin: 10% 10% 10% 10%;
 padding: 5%;
 flex-direction: column;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.info-content h2 {
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 10%;
}
.info-content p {
 margin: 5% 0;
}
.info-content button {
 background-color: transparent;
 opacity: 0.5;
 font-weight: bolder;
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 align-self: flex-end;
 position: absolute;
 font-size: 1.5rem;
}

canvas {
 height: 80vh !important;
}
.rotation {
 height: 10vh;
 width: 80%;
 margin: 5vh 10%;
 display: flex;
 order: 2;
}
.rotation span {
 flex: 1 1 0;
}
.rotation i {
    border: solid black;
    border-width: 0 15px 15px 0;
    display: inline-block;
 width: 5vh;
    height: 5vh;
}
.rotation .right {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.rotation .left {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
}

@media all and (max-width: 650px) {
 .info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
 }
 .info-title {
  display: none;
 }
 .info-content {
  height: 80%;
 }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="model">
        <div class="webgl">
            <div class="rotation">
                <i class="arrow left"></i>
                <span></span>
                <i class="arrow right"></i>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="info">
            <h1 class="info-title">AION</h1>
            <div class="info-content">
                <h2>Apartamento N</h2>
                <p>
                    <strong>Status:</strong> Vendido | A venda | Reservado
                </p>
                <p>
                    <strong>Tamanho:</strong> 00.0 x 00.0 x 00.0
                </p>
                <button>X</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/94/three.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Os eventos de rotação funcionam como esperado em qualquer tipo de device e em qualquer tamanho da tela

Retirei a parte de criação dos apartamentos e adicionei o evento de click apenas no prédio para não deixar o script muito grande

Edit:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara to achando que o seu problema é com o CSS. Faz um teste ai, pode até tirar a maquete e o JS, apenas teste o layout. Coloca uma cor de fundo em cada div que vai receber o conteúdo e testa a responsividade delas. Veja se essas display:flex que vc usou e os positions estão funcionando da maneira correta primeiro

Comment: @hugocsl testei como você falou, e, olhando nas ferramentas de desenvolvedor do chromium, o css que deveria ser aplicado aos elementos quando a tela for menor que 650px não aparecem, mas o código foi carregado e aparece dentro do arquivo css em sources, alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: Vc colocou a regra @media direitinho, elá tem que ser a última coisa do seu CSS, depois que vc escrever tudo no final de tudo do CSS. Testa tirando essa all, tenta assim `@media screen and (max-width: 650x)`

Comment: Sim está no final do arquivo, já tentei com screen, all e sem nenhum, os três não funcionaram, o estranho é que o css nem aparece nas ferramentas de desenvolvedor, nem que fosse riscado, pelo menos saberia que tem algo sobre escrevendo

Comment: Acho que descobri seu problema! É a div class .info que está por cima do elemento clicável, então o seu click não atinge o elemento que deveria. Faz um teste simples e coloca o `@media (max-width: 650px) { .info {display:none } }` e tenta clicar pra ver se funciona

Comment: Sim é isso, o problema agora é entender o porque do css não esta funcionando, fiz mais uns testes, e o css da media query não está aparecendo apenas no device mobile (touch e no touch), no desktop funciona como esperado

Comment: Cara se o @media não estivesse funcionando ele nem estaria dando display:none no .info. Qual CSS mais precisamente não está funcionando, e qual elemento não esta recebendo esse estilo?

Comment: Nenhum estilo do `@media ...` está funcionando, mudei o `display: none;` direto nas ferramentas de desenvolvedor

Comment: Aqui não tenho como testar em dispositivos mobile, mas no meu Chrome Desktop e pelo DevTools fica tudo direitinho, pega as classes e fica responsivo... Vc pode tentar colocar !important nos estilos, se não der certo é pq algum JS está sobrescrevendo as classes pelo script

Comment: @hugocsl infelizmente não é isso, testei e continuou na mesma, adicionei um print da tela para você ver o que eu estou vendo, tanto o mobile touch como o no touch acontece o mesmo, se eu mudar o tipo do device para de funcionar (mesmo recarregando a página), testando no celular fica igual a segunda imagem

Comment: Mobile (no touch) é dispositivo móvel sem touche screen, é isso mesmo que vc precisa? Su página vai rodar em celulares SEM touch na tela??

Comment: Acredito que não mas com touch o mesmo erro acontece, não to entendendo o que está acontecendo, tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Eu testei aqui e mesmo No Touch ele está aplicando o CSS, não estou usando seus JS na página pq testei só o layout. Se mesmo no mobile comum der problema é pq seu JS está colocando estilos no elemento

Comment: Estranho, será que é a biblioteca do three? Os únicos js que tenho para mudar o estilo dos elementos mudam apenas o `display` do card e o `margin-top` do título (AION)